# tikzpicture is not at the center although "centering" command

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, horizontal-alignment

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark,
    fit
}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Clock}{O{1cm}O{\large}O{cyan}}{%
\def\radius{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=0.055*\radius]
\filldraw [fill=#3] (0,0) circle [radius=\radius];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.9*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
  \node[font=#2] at (\angle:0.68*\radius) {\textsf{\xi}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \draw[line width=0.04*\radius] (\angle:0.82*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
\draw (0,0) -- (120:0.4*\radius);
\draw (0,0) -- (90:0.5*\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    %\begin{equation}
    %\begin{aligned}
    U = 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]{
            \node[rectangle,draw=red,anchor=base,text width=2cm, label= below:text] 
            {$e^{-i \Circled[outer color=green]{\gamma_e B_0}  S_z t}$
            \quad\Clock[0.9 cm][\footnotesize][green]
            };
            \hspace{2.3cm}
            \node[rectangle,draw=red,anchor=base,text width=2cm, label= below:text2] 
            {$e^{-i \Circled[outer color=pink]{\gamma_n B_0}  I_{z1} t}$
            \quad\Clock[0.9 cm][\footnotesize][pink]
            };
            \hspace{2.3cm}
            \node[rectangle,draw=red,anchor=base,text width=2cm, label= below:text2] 
            {$e^{-i \Circled[outer color=orange]{\gamma_n B_0}  I_{z2} t}$
            \quad\Clock[0.9 cm][\footnotesize][orange]
            };
            \hspace{2.3cm}
            \node[rectangle,draw=red,anchor=base,text width=2cm, label= below:text2] 
            {$e^{-i \Circled[outer color=yellow]{A_1}  S_zI_{z1} t}$
            \quad\Clock[0.9 cm][\footnotesize][yellow]
            };
            \hspace{2.3cm}
            \node[rectangle,draw=red,anchor=base,text width=2cm, label= below:text2] 
            {$e^{-i \Circled[outer color=cyan]{A_1}  S_zI_{z1} t}$
            \quad\Clock[0.9 cm][\footnotesize][cyan]
            };
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %\end{aligned}
%\end{equation}

    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:trying}
\end{figure}
```

As an output, my image is not centered. It starts from center and goes until the right end of the page. I am trying to find a way to center the whole image rather than starting from center. However, I could not make it. Does anyone has an idea about how to do it?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for warning! sorry I was trying to center it for a while and I have just pasted here without being careful

Comment: Can you puzzle your code blocks together into one single block which is ready for copy&pasting so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hope it is fine now.

Comment: Did you test the code from your question? No `document` environment, not all packages necessary to compile your code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting tikzpictures into nodes of other tikzpictures is almost never a good idea.

Instead you could use `\fcolorbox` to create the red box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usetikzlibrary{
arrows,
calc,
chains,
decorations,
decorations.text,
decorations.pathmorphing,
matrix,
positioning,
shapes,
tikzmark,
fit
}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Clock}{O{1cm}O{\large}O{cyan}}{%
\def\radius{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=0.055*\radius]
\filldraw [fill=#3] (0,0) circle [radius=\radius];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.9*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
\node[font=#2] at (\angle:0.68*\radius) {\textsf{\xi}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=0.04*\radius] (\angle:0.82*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
\draw (0,0) -- (120:0.4*\radius);
\draw (0,0) -- (90:0.5*\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  U = 
  \parbox{2.5cm}{%
    \centering%
    \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\parbox{2.3cm}{%
      \centering
      $e^{-i \Circled[outer color=green]{A1}  \text{something} t}$

      \Clock[0.9cm][\footnotesize][green]
    }}

    Text 1
  }
  \parbox{2.5cm}{%
    \centering%
    \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\parbox{2.3cm}{%
      \centering
      $e^{-i \Circled[outer color=pink]{\gamma_n B_0}  I_{z1} t}$

      \Clock[0.9cm][\footnotesize][green]
    }}

    Text 2
  }
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:trying}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me until the fifth term. The fifth term is appearing below line.

Comment: well actually, I can solve it! Thanks :)

Comment: @j.doe If the 5th term is in the line below, then there is not enough space for your figure

Comment: exactly, I just noticed that